# Does the paper "On the difficulty of training Recurrent Neural Networks" (2013) assume, falsely, that spectral radii are $\ge$ square matrix norms?

Tags: papers, vanishing-gradient-problem

([link to paper in arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.5063.pdf))

In section **2.1** the authors define $\gamma$ as the maximum possible value of the derivative of the activation function (e.g. 1 for tanh.) Then they have this to say:

> We first prove that it is sufficient for $\lambda_1 < \frac{1}{\gamma}$, where $\lambda_1$ is the absolute value of the largest eigenvalue of the recurrent weight matrix $W_{rec}$, for the vanishing gradient problem to occur.

Then they use the submultiplicity ($\|AB\| \le \|A\|\|B\|$) of the 2-norm of the Jacobians to obtain the following inequality:

$$ \forall x, \| \frac{\partial x_{k+1}}{\partial x_k} \| \le \| W_{rec}^\top \| \| diag(\sigma'(x_k))\| < \frac{1}{\gamma} \gamma < 1 $$

Here

- $x_k$ is the pre-activated state vector of the RNN
- $W_{rec}$ is the weight matrix between states (i.e. $x_k = W_{rec} \times \sigma(x_{k-1}) + b$ )
- $\sigma()$ is the activation function for the state vector
- $diag(v)$ is the diagonal matrix version of a vector $v$

They appear to be either substituting the norm of the weight matrix $\|W_{rec}^\top\|$ for its largest eigenvalue $|\lambda_1|$ (eigenvalues are the same for transposes) or just assuming that this norm is less than or equal to the eigenvalue. This bothers me because the norm of a matrix is bounded *below*, not above, by this eigenvalue/spectral radius ([see lemma 10 here](https://www.math.drexel.edu/~foucart/TeachingFiles/F12/M504Lect6.pdf) and this [math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583417/spectral-radius-is-not-matrix-norm))

They seem to assume that

$$\| W_{rec}^\top \| \le \lambda_1 < \frac{1}{\gamma}  $$

But really

$$ \| W_{rec}^\top \| \ge \lambda_1 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error. But it is also not the in final version of the paper (arxiv.) The final version of the paper can be found [here](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/pascanu13.pdf) where they replace "absolute value of the largest [eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)" with "largest [singular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value)".

> We first prove that it is sufficient for $\lambda_1 < \frac{1}{\gamma}$, where $\lambda_1$ is the largest singular value of $W_{rec}$, for the vanishing gradient problem to occur.

Comment: For a proof that their substitution works with the the maximum singular value and the 2-norm, see Theorem 4.2 of in chapter 4 of  [Lectures on Dynamic Systems and
 Control](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_241JS11_chap04.pdf)